# IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample not called -- custom media sink

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have written a custom media sink (to control a hardware video output board).  This had been working as expected for the better part of a year. Things stopped working when I recompiled the sink.  I noticed that the Media Foundation libraries and dlls were updated several weeks before the recompile.  MFTrace shows that the topology has the expected blocks are connected in the expected topology.  The MediaTypes are also proper.  When the Presentation Clock is started, I send an MEStreamSinkStarted event followed by a MEStreamSinkRequestSample event.  Both events are being read, but ProcessSample is never called.  The video file is playing; the audio stream is processed normally. I can play the video file successfully to the EVR through TopoEdit.  That the problem occurred after a recompile and not after a Windows update suggests (to me) an interface change of some sort-- perhaps a previously optional function is now required -- but I have not found any reference to a change.  I am nearly out of ideas.

Here is the function that queues the sample request:

```
HRESULT BmDstream::OnStarted(void)
{

    OutputDebugString(_T("BmDstream::OnStarted()"));
    FAIL_RETURN(QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkStarted, GUID_NULL, S_OK, NULL));
    OutputDebugString(_T("BmDstream  -- Requesting sample"));
    FAIL_RETURN(QueueEvent(MEStreamSinkRequestSample, GUID_NULL, S_OK, NULL));

    return (S_OK);
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa (as always).  At the same time I recompiled the sink, I made another change that I also suspected, but examined 3 times without finding the bug.  I inadvertently instantiated the source twice. One instance was used for the audio, the other for the video.  Apparently the video source was never started.  Nothing to do with the sink, Windows updates, or anything except me.  Aargh!